# How to define the sequence of array elements?

Tags: php

I have got the following array.

```
Array
        (
            [1] => a
            [2] => b
            [3] => c
            [4] => d
            [5] => e
            [6] => f
            [7] => g
            [8] => h
            [9] => i
            [11] => j
            [13] => k
            [14] => l
            [15] => m
            [16] => n
            [17] => o
            [18] => p
            [19] => q
            [20] => r
            [21] => s
            [22] => t
            [23] => u
            [24] => v
            [25] => w
        )
```

as you can see number 10 and 12 don't exist. 
Is there a function, so that my array has a range from 1 to 23? So that it would look like this?

```
Array
        (
            [1] => a
            [2] => b
            [3] => c
            [4] => d
            [5] => e
            [6] => f
            [7] => g
            [8] => h
            [9] => i
            [10] => j
            [11] => k
            [12] => l
            [13] => m
            [14] => n
            [15] => o
            [16] => p
            [17] => q
            [18] => r
            [19] => s
            [20] => t
            [21] => u
            [22] => v
            [23] => w
        )
```

I hope you understand my problem. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want a zero-indexed array:

```
$new = array_values($array);
```

If you want to start with an aribitrary number (in this case: 1);

```
$new = array_combine(range(1,count($array)),array_values($array));
```

Answer (score 3):

What about [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) ?

```
$array = range('a', 'w');
```

**Update:** oh, you wan't from `1` to `23`. Here you go:

```
$array = array_combine(range(1,23), range('a', 'w'));
```

Answer (score 2):

This snippet will do:

```
$new = Array();
$i = 1;
foreach ($original as $element) {
    $new[$i] = $element;
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use array values to get the full list of keys assuming that its ok for the indexes to run from 0->22 as opposed to 1->23.

If the indexes need to begin at 1 then add an extra step to shift the indexes forward:

```
$newArray = array_values($array);

$startAtIndex1Array = array();
//shift indexes to start at 1
foreach($newArray as $key=>$value) {
    $startAtIndex1Array[$key+1] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$tmpArray = Array
        (
            [1] => a
            [2] => b
            [3] => c
            [4] => d
            [5] => e
            [6] => f
            [7] => g
            [8] => h
            [9] => i
            [11] => j
            [13] => k
            [14] => l
            [15] => m
            [16] => n
            [17] => o
            [18] => p
            [19] => q
            [20] => r
            [21] => s
            [22] => t
            [23] => u
            [24] => v
            [25] => w
        );

foreach($tmpArray as $v){
  $tmpArray2[count($tmpArray2)] = $v;
}
```

It will do what you want but you should consider starting your arrays by a key = 0